# bash - losing data when writing to a file within for loop

Tags: linux, bash

I'm using a bash to run a program for 50 times and append the output into a log file. However, when it finishes running, I just got about 4 outputs in the log file (whereas I should have got 50 outputs). My code is:

```
#!/bin/bash

mypath="crossvalidation/abalone"
outpath="output/abalone"

for j in {1..5}
do
    for i in {0..9}
    do
        ./myprogram -fopen "$mypath/${i}" -fout "$outpath/log.out" #write to file
       #./myprogram -fopen "$mypath/${i}" -lstd  #print to screen

    done
done
```

If I just print the output to the screen (like the what second line does in the loop), it seems that it keeps printing things out and things are not missing. So what could possibly be happening here? Why am I losing so much data in my output file?

Comment: The issue is in "myprogram", not the shell script.

Comment: Have you tried `./myprogram -fopen "$mypath/$i" -lstd >> "$outpath/log.out"`

Comment: Also try `/myprogram -fopen "$mypath/${i}" -fout "$outpath/log_${i}_${j}.out"`